# ExtJs List not showed in a container

Tags: list, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a container with three items:

```
ombrelloneButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
id: 'btnOmbr',
iconMask: true,
iconCls: 'action',
text: 'Ombrellone'
});

lettinoButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
id: 'btnLett',
iconMask: true,
iconCls: 'action',
text: 'Lettino'
});

toolbarPostazione = Ext.create('Ext.Toolbar',{
layout: {
    pack: 'center'
}, // layout
ui: 'plain',
items: [ombrelloneButton,
    lettinoButton]
});

Ext.define('appTrial.view.Postazione.Postazione',{
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
xtype: 'Postazione',
alias: 'widget.Postazione',

controllers:['AssociaAttivitaController'],

models : ['appTrial.model.AttivitaModel'],

config : {
    id : 'PostazioneId',

    title : 'Welcome',
    resizable : false,
    collapsible : true,
    bodyPadding : '5',
    buttonAlign : 'center',
    border : false,
    trackResetOnLoad : true,

    items : [{
        docked: 'top',
        xtype: 'titlebar',
        title: 'Welcome to My New App!!!'
        },
        {
        xtype: 'container',
        name: 'mainContainer',
        id: 'postazioneContainer',
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'center',
            pack: 'center'
        },
        //width : '100%',
            items : [{
                layout: {
                    pack: 'center'
                },
                html :'<p style="color: red; text-align: center; font-size: 20px" >Complimenti!</p><br><p style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px">Sei stato associato alla attivita '+dummyAttivita.get('nomeAttivita')+'!</p>' +
                    '<br><p style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px">Ora associa la tua postazione:</p>',
                margin: '80 0 50 0'
            },
                toolbarPostazione,
                {
                    xtype: 'PostazioniList',
                    title:'PostazioniAssociate',
                    id: 'PostazioniAssociate'
                }
            ]
    }]
}

});
```

The first two of them are showed (html text and toolbar), while the PostazioniList is not showed.
It is done like this (List.js):

```
Ext.define('appTrial.view.Postazione.List', {
extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype: 'PostazioniList',
alias: 'widget.PostazioniList',

itemTpl: '<div>{tipoPostazione} num.{numPostazione}</div>',

data: [{
    tipoPostazione: 'Ombrellone',
    numPostazione: '5'
},
{
    tipoPostazione: 'Ombrellone',
    numPostazione: '37'
},
{
    tipoPostazione: 'Lettino',
    numPostazione: '46d'
}]
});
```

Could it be a html problem?
I don't understand also why I don't get any error, just it is hidden...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have been able to show the list setting height and width, but the text is not shown...any help?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are trying to show the list inside a container, which is then inside a form?

Comment: No, it's the structure that I used at the beginning; then I moved the form stuff inside the"toolbarPostazione" and for this reason now I'm trying to make the Home as simple Ext.tab.Panel, but I get the following error:"Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.Container#doAdd] Adding a card to a tab container without specifying any tab configuration". Any idea?